# What value of $z$ should I take to find this tangent plane equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

I have the surface: $z^2 = xy$

I want to find the tangent plane and normal line to this surface at the point $(x,y)=(1,4)$

I know how to do this but in this case I'm confused as to what I should use as my $z$ value? In order to find it I substituted the given $x$ and $y$ values into the surface equation, by doing this I obtained $z^2 = 4$.

Here I'm not sure whether I should use $2$ or $-2$ as my $z$ value since $\sqrt4 = +-(2)$ or does it not matter what $z$ value I use  and either one is fine?

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will have two tangent planes - one at $(1, 4, 2)$ and the other at $(1, 4, -2)$

Comment: So i need to calculate two different tangent planes and two different normal lines?

Comment: In the question they say find the tangent plane, not planes, should I still calculate both or do you think one is sufficient?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Also, you can write it as $f(x, y, z) = z^2 - xy = 0$ and then find $(f_x, f_y, f_z)$ as the gradient. That gives you normal line and then use that to find equation of the plane.

Comment: All I can say that there are two tangent planes to the cone for any $x, y$ values (either both $x, y$ positive or both $x, y$ negative) - one for negative $z$ and one for positive $z$. Whether you will find one or both, I will leave it to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

IF you have quoted the problem exactly as it was given to you then it is just a badly written problem!  It ask you to find **the** tangent plane at **the** point where x= 1, y= 4 when, in fact, there are two such points and two such planes.
$\nabla z^2- xy= -y\vec{i}- x\vec{j}+ 2z\vec{k}$.

The normal vector at (1,4,2) is $-4\vec{i}- \vec{j}+ 4\vec{k}$ and the tangent plane there is $-4(x-1)- (y-1)+ 4z= 0$.

The normal vector at (1,4,-2) is $-4\vec{i}- \vec{j}- 4\vec{k}$ and the tangent plane there is $-4(x-1)- (y-1)- 4z= 0$.